# Why does `functools.partial` not inherit `__name__` and other meta data by default?

Tags: python, functools

I am wondering why meta data (e.g. `__name__`, `__doc__`) for the wrapped method/function by [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) is not inherited by default. Instead, `functools` provides the [`update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) function.

Why it is not done by default is not mentioned anywhere (as far as I could see) e.g. [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0309/) and many tutorials on `functools.partial` talk about how to "solve the issue" of a missing `__name__`.

Are there examples where inheriting this information causes problems/confusion?

Comment: We aren't really in a position to explain someone else's design decision, unless it was documented somewhere (in which case it would be [better to try to look it up yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)). That said, the inherited data might not be accurate

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Think about what that would actually look like:

```
def add(x, y):
    "Adds two numbers"
    return x + y

add_5 = partial(add, 5)
```

Would it actually make sense for `add_5` to have `__name__` set to `"add"` and `__doc__` set to `"Adds two numbers"`?

The callable created by `partial` behaves completely differently from the original function. It wouldn't be appropriate for the new callable to inherit the name and docstring of a function with completely different behavior.

Comment: I went on a bit of a wild goose chase with this thinking about nested functions, lambdas etc, but it really is that simple. Thank you for the insight.